# access an instance of class in the Page_init

Tags: c#, namespaces

Basically i am trying to create an instance of class and use in the Page_init but somehow can not access the instance or cannot create the instance at all. Tried to add the namespace in the webconfig file also but no luck.

Below gives **dh** does not exist in the current context error.

```
<script runat="server" language="C#">    
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataHelper dh = new DataHelper();
        dh.Parameter("my param");

    }
</script>
```

Below gives "are you missing a namespace error."

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsites_Project.Microsites_Library" %>

<%  
     DataHelper dh = new DataHelper();
%>

<script runat="server" language="C#">    
   protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       dh.Parameter("my param");

   }
</script>
```

any help in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you have a code behind?

Comment: @PatrickHofman The CMS that I'm using wont allow me to use "System.Web.UI.Page" so I can't

Comment: Then use another base type.

Comment: @PatrickHofman What do you mean, such as?

Comment: The base type it requires. I don't know which CMS you are using or the page type it expects, so I can't help you on that.

Comment: The CMS is Crownpeak, could not found any base type even in their documentation.